# python - how to pass variables between instances while using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a tool for adapting raw data formats to use between data acquisition systems

```
class Main_Window_App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        file = tk.Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label = 'Open', command = self._return_file_data)
        menu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)

    def _return_file_data(self):
        global data 
        CSV_gather = self.CSV_gatherer()
        data = CSV_gather.data_Dataframe
        file_list = list(data.keys())
        Main_Window_App._reset_option_menu(self,file_list, 0)

    class CSV_gatherer():
        def __init__(self):
            self.data_Dataframe = self.ReadFiles(self.get_file_names())
        def get_file_names(self):
            #uses askopenfilenames to gather a set of file names
        def ReadFiles(self,Input_Files):
            #reads the files into a set of dataFrames
app = Main_Window_App()
app.mainloop()
```

my question: is there a better way to be able to access the variable named data or better yet the entire instance CSV_gather within app? I have been reading that using global is un-pythonic and I am trying to write code in the best way possible. Normally, I would just return the variable and place it into a different variable in the app instance, however because I am calling it through a command in tkinter, I can't do that.

Comment: In my opinion, using a global is fine as long as a) it's needed for multiple classes/functions (like in your case) and b) you don't have too many of them.

Comment: If you want to access `data` _within app_, change `data` to instance variable `self.data`.

Comment: who would have thunk it was so easy to just add self.... Thank you @acw1668